# Get Current Path of Page in Middleman Layout File

Tags: ruby, middleman

Is it possible to retrieve the current path of a page in a middleman file?  For instance, if I have a layout file `layout.erb` with something like the following:

```
<%= page.path %>
<%= yield %>
```

and a test file `index.html`:

```
Testing
```

then when Middleman rendered the page I would get something like:

```
/index.html
Testing
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Middleman also provides the `current_page` variable.  `current_page.path` is the source path of this resource (relative to the source directory, without template extensions) and `current_page.url` is the path without the directory index (so `foo/index.html` becomes just `foo`).

```
<%= current_page.path %>
# -> index.html

<%= current_page.url %>
# -> /
```

Details from Middleman's `Middleman::Sitemap::Resource` rubydoc.
http://rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Sitemap/Resource

Comment: This is probably the best way to get the current path considering it's exposed and documented.

Comment: Any idea how to get the hostname?

Comment: Is that possible if we get the port name ? I want to separate the staging url and production url @Nick

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
<%= request.path %>
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say when Middleman builds the application it creates a server, requests the pageas in the application and writes the responses to files. But I honestly don't know.

Comment: @jackyalcine it is aliased to the resource object for the current path https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/dd0ee24ca3ae728b00f8987d74c360557c910946/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/template_context.rb#L165